# Diameter Gx RAR getting failed at Seagull in Throttling QoS scenarios

Tags: diameter-protocol

I am doing testing for the Gx interface in cloud native environment through seagull where I had to consume the data balance completely and the QoS should get updated through Throttling PCC Rule.
In the seagull simulator I getting all the Diameter Messages in sequence but the execution getting failed when the seagull is receiving the Gx RAR from pcrf with updated PCC rule. After receiving the RAR seagull is throwing "DIAMETER_UNABLE_TO_DELIVER" in Gx RAA.

I need confirmation on whether seagull is capable of handling Gx RAR messages ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MRUy.png)

All the dictionary files, scenario files and the environment variables are in place.